# Cassandra read consistency is one, but node connects to another node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

3 node cluster and RF of 3 means every node has all the data. Consistency is ONE.
So when queried for some data on node-1, ideally as node-1 has all the data it should be able to complete my query.

But when I checked how my query is running using 'tracing on', it shows me that it connects to node-2 also, which is not needed as per my understanding.

Am I missing something here ? 
Thanks in advance.

Edited ::

Added the [output of 'tracing on'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDhRD.png).
It can be seen in the image that, node 10.101.201.3 has contacted 10.101.201.4

Comment: can you show the tracing output?

Comment: @AlexOtt https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDhRD.png this is the output of 'tracing on'

Comment: Are you running your query from cqlsh or from application code?

Comment: @Aaron from cqlsh

Comment: @Aaron does this change if I'm running the query from application code ?

Answer (score 1):

> 3 node cluster and RF of 3 means every node has all the data.

Just because every node has 100% of all data, does not mean that every node has 100% of all token ranges.  The token ranges in a 3 node cluster will be split-up evenly @ ~33% each.

In short, `node-1` may *have* all of the data, but it's only *primarily* responsible for 33% of it.  When the partition key is hashed, the query is likely being directed toward `node-2` because it is *primarily* responsible for that partition key...despite the fact that the other nodes contain secondary and tertiary replicas.

> cqlsh.  Does this change if I'm running the query from application code?

Yes, because the specified load balancing policy (configured in app code) can also affect this behavior.